# Android testing: asserting an activity transitioned to another

Tags: android, testing, android-activity, junit, activity-lifecycle

I am looking at [tests on Android activities](https://developer.android.com/tools/testing/activity_testing.html). I would like to test the [activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) and particularly the end of my activity to start another activity (I am testing the end of the first activity, not the start of the second). I am using [ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.html) and Android Espresso with JUnit 4 tests.

I have tried to assert that once I trigger the end of an activity, by pressing a button on the screen, the activity is paused or not visible but I ran out of luck so far. Is there any good practice to test transitions between activities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at https://developer.android.com/training/activity-testing/activity-functional-testing.html#activitymonitor.

Basically you'll need to add and register an [`ActivityMonitor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor.html) in your instrumented functional test, which will be set up to listen for your second `Activity`. Once the trigger happens (ie a button being clicked in your test case) you will just use  [`waitForActivityWithTimeout(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor.html#waitForActivityWithTimeout%28long%29) to get the instance of the second `Activity`.

If the call times out, or the result is null, then you know your second `Activity` hasn't been started. You can also assert on the `Activity` instances whether they're finishing/destroyed/etc depending on what you are expecting to happen with them.